# Showing correctly formatted product price in Shopify raw tags

Tags: php, shopify

Inside raw tags in my shopify theme I have a problem where I can output the price of a product (ie 1400 00) but can't format the price to show (£1400). The tag I'm using to pull through the formatted price is ${price} but when I try ${ price | money_with_currency } nothing shows.

Does anyone know how I can get the currency show without the trailing decimals?

Answer (score 1):

Try either the [`money`](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/money-filters#money) or [`money_without_trailing_zeros`](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/money-filters#money_without_trailing_zeros) filters.

E.g.

```
{{ price | money }}
{{ price | money_without_trailing_zeros }}
```

See the [money filters documentation here](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/money-filters).

If you want to use `money_with_currency`, but don't want the trailing decimals, you can go to Settings > General > Currency > Change Formatting and replace `${{amount}} AUD` with `${{amount_no_decimals}} AUD`.

Comment: Hi there Steph, yeah I tried money and money without trailing zeros first up but they didn't play nice with the {raw} tags. I've ended up stripping the price out completely.